# Angularjs y rutas con #!

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

tengo una web con angularjs 1.6.4 y cuando ingreso a http://www.misitio.com/mercado/index.html automaticamente me agrega #! y ingresa a

```
http://www.misitio.com/mercado/index.html#!/
```

En un principio n me molestaba y hice todo el sitio sin problemas, con entityframework y web api.
El problema ocurre al querer compartir en el front enlaces del estilo 
http://www.misitio.com/mercado/web/#!/44
Este enlace funciona si lo copio y pego en el navegador, me trae el producto con Id 44, el problema es al compartir este enlace en facebook , whatsapp etc, me locorta y solo comparte

```
http://www.misitio.com/mercado/web
```

Ya probé con lo siguiente para quitar los #!

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

y tambien con javascript con un encode

nada me funciona, alguien sabe que puedo hacer?
gracias

Comment: te ha servido la respuesta?

Comment: aun sigues teniendo problema?

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver tu problema prueba lo siguiente: 
1- Agrega esto dentro de la etiqueta `<head>`

```
<base href="/" />
```

2- Usa esto en `app.config`

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Comment: No,me queda la pantalla en blanco, lo deje de esa manera, cuando haga otro proyecto tendré que corroborar primero de sacar de ese modo el #!. Gracias igual

Comment: @Lucho Si crees que esta respuesta fue una solución a tu pregunta, marca como correcta.